# Error in building APK in KIVY

Tags: android, python, virtual-machine, kivy, buildozer

I'm using the Kivy Android VM with complete pre-requisite mentioned in their site.

Here is my reference:
[The Kivy Android Virtual Machine](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android-vm.html)

On step 6 it says follow the read me file on desktop.

So the step on read me file, `buildozer init` on my project directory has no problem. Doing the `buildozer android debug`, it produces this error:

[image]

Thanks in advance for help! :)

**UPDATE: log_level=2 applied**

[image]

Comment: Do you have log_level=2 enabled?

Comment: ok i ran again with 'log_level=2' still error occur. I'll post an update.

Comment: why it seems like i'm lacking of files? the VM came from their site...

Comment: Is it using an up to date buildozer and python-for-android?

Comment: This error probably relates to the building of ctypes (obviously), but this is important because in particular this functionality was only added relatively recently. I ask about the versions of buildozer and python-for-android because I think this can happen if they're out of date or mismatched.

Comment: @inclement so i tried to use the command git clone for buildozer even though it said to skip it. i do have now a different error, **unzip: cannot find zipfile directory...** for **stable.zip**. though when i look into the directory it is there and using the command `file` it mention that it is zip archived data

Comment: On top of changing log_level to 2, try running the buildozer command with verbose ex: buildozer --verbose android etc. It pretty much tells you what it's doing every step of the way which might narrow down the problem areas.

Comment: also, try redirecting the whole output to a pastebin website, using for example `buildozer android debug >& | pastebinit` (and give us the link to the log)  maybe an important error is hidden before this one.